# Make JEditable revert to displaying the edit-in-place textarea if the submit fails?

Tags: jquery, jeditable

I'm using `Jeditable` with `jQuery` and it is mostly working how I want it.  When the user submits some changes via `jeditable` (I'm using a `textarea`) and the server determines that there are some validation errors, I want to automatically revert to displaying the `textarea` containing the user's most recent changes.  This is to avoid them losing the text they had typed in (it may have been a result of a server-side error or hitting the submit button accidentally before they are ready).

Is there any easy way to have `jeditable` build the edit control anew?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so here's what I did to solve this.  I hacked `jeditable.js` so that it expects JSON data as the response in the AJAX `success` callback triggered when submitting the in-place edit.  In the JSON object is an `alert` field which I use as so

```
var ajaxoptions = {
  type    : 'POST',
  data    : submitdata,
  dataType: 'text',
  accepts: 'json',
  url     : settings.target,
  success : function(result, status) {
      data = $.parseJSON(result);
      $(self).children('span.indicator').remove();
      if(!data.alert) {
        $(self).html(data.text);
        self.editing = false;
        callback.apply(self, [data, settings]);
        if (!$.trim($(self).html())) {
            $(self).html(settings.placeholder);
        }
      }
      else {
        callback.apply(self, [data, settings]);
      }
  },
  error   : function(xhr, status, error) {
      $(self).children('span.indicator').remove();
      onerror.apply(form, [settings, self, xhr]);
  }
```

};

So, in essence, if there is a non-NULL alert string, I just don't to anything (except trigger the `callback` function, if defined).  This seems to work fine, leaving the `textarea` field in place with the user's changes inside it.  My callback alerts the user that the change wasn't submitted by using the text in `data.alert`.